# Angular route param is empty

Tags: angular

I have a routerlink that looks like this:

```
  <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-content-center" *ngFor = "let union of activeUnions" [routerLink] = "['union',union.id]">
```

Which is routing using the route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IndexPage
  },
  {
    path:"new",
    component:NewPage
  },
  {
    path:"union/:id",
    component:UnionPage
  }
];
```

This is sending me to the required component but when i try to get the id like such

```
  ngOnInit() {
    let id = this.$common.$route.snapshot.paramMap
    console.log(id);
  }
```

I am getting an empty object instead of an object containing the id from the url, whats is wrong?

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: You should probably try to provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing. Ideally, someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like Stackblitz [(link here!)](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular-ivy) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it. There should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Is the ID visible in the URL?

Comment: Yes the id is in the url @oscar

Comment: Move this code within constructor and see if that helps!

Comment: Take a look at the demo i did for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wrgfwa?file=src/app/union-page/union-page.component.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you can get the desired **id** with this:

```
...
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
...

constructor(
   ...
   private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
   ...
) {}


 ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = Number(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
    console.log(id);
  }
```

Comment: This must work, but remember that this captures the value of ID just once at the ngOnInit. If the id changes while the component is active, the value in the component won't change

Comment: This worked, this was what i was doing but the activatedRoute was in a common service that was imported together, why did this hinder it from working?